# AWS Subdomain not working with Github Pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, dns, subdomain, github-pages

I'm trying to get one of my subdomains to link to my Github project.

I created a CNAME in the Route 53 console for "kushyapp.github.io/kushy-blog-gatsby" and set it to update every minute.

When I use the dig command to check the domain's config (`dig blog.kushy.net +nostats +nocomments +nocmd`), I can see my Github project in the output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> blog.kushy.net +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
;; global options: +cmd
;blog.kushy.net.            IN  A
blog.kushy.net.     300 IN  CNAME   kushyapp.github.io/kushy-blog-gatsby.
.           83449   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018072000 1800 900 604800 86400
```

When I visit the domain (blog.kushy.net) I see the error:

```
This site can’t be reached
blog.kushy.net’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong in the configuration? I've tried enabling/disabling the domain and adding a CNAME file to the repo.

If it counts for anything, this subdomain was recently hosted on a nginx server (no domain setup in Route 53, only in nginx virtual host file). I removed old nginx configs and restarted the server (and I don't see it in the dig output) - so I'm fairly sure this isn't the issue.

Comment: Pretty sure CNAME records have to point at a domain, not a resource on a domain

Comment: `CNAME   kushyapp.github.io/kushy-blog-gatsby.` this is invalid the target of a `CNAME` record type should be an hostname.

Comment: @miknik yep! that was it, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63785511/forward-traffic-from-www-subdomain-to-apex-domain-in-aws-route-53

Answer (score -1):

Ended up being an issue where I was routing it to REPO(YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME.github.io/REPO_NAME), not my GITHUB PAGES ROOT URL (YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME.github.io).

CNAME require root level URLs, no subdirectories. Github handles the redirect to the repo on their end.