# Forward traffic from www subdomain to apex domain in AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

My site works with [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), but when I browse to mydomain.com, there is no IP address found. I am trying to use Route 53 and create an ALIAS record from mydomain.com to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com). All the documentation and help on the Internet says to create an alias record. However, ALIAS is not a record type that is available from the drop-down. How does on create an alias record in Route 53?

I understand that mydomain.com is what is referred to an an "apex record", is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The alias record is an option in a record type, **not an independent record type** as show for example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/).

In Route53 to redirect `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com` you can create **simple record** with `Alias to other record` option:

[image]

Comment: I fil in "www.mydomain.com" in the third text box under "Value/Route traffic to" and I get 'Alias Target contains an invalid value. (InvalidChangeBatch 400: "" is not a valid hosted zone id. is not a valid encrypted identifier." There is an A record for www.mydomain.com pointing to the github URL that is hosting my home page.

Comment: @AnnaNaden Are the two records in same hosted zone?

Comment: Yes they are. When I go to the third text box under Value/Route traffic to, it says "no resources found." There is no option to add a resource; in fact there is no mention of "resource" anywhere in the UI. What is the relationship of "resources" to DNS records? Is "resource" just another name for DNS record?

Comment: This is not a redirect in the HTML sense. The page will still load with/without www, it doesn't redirect to one.

Answer (score 0):

I  got it working by creating an A record pointing to the Github IP addresses that host my webpage. It wouldn't let me create an A record pointing to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

Comment: CNAME is for hostnames, A records for ip adresses.

Answer (score 0):

An APEX record is the "naked domain" marked with a leading `@` symbol often. They don't have aliases  usually, just IPs. [AWS allows you to set an alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) to it due to their own DNS extension. You can still create subdomains and point to any other name/address.

Take this as an example of what the DNS zone file would look like (ipv4/ipv6):

```
yourdomain.com.        IN A         <first github pages ipv4 address>
yourdomain.com.        IN A         <second github pages ipv4 address>
yourdomain.com.        IN A         <third github pages ipv4 address>
yourdomain.com.        IN AAAA      <github pages ipv6 address>
www                    IN CNAME     <first github pages address>
www                    IN CNAME     <second github pages address>
```

To get your whole domain pointing to github pages, you need to add the IP address / addresses to the first `A` record in the example above.

**You can find the IP addresses for GitHub pages on this link:**

```
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain